# Matching the begining and the end of line

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

```
^Category:\s(.*Movies|Movies RU|Sports|Movies HD| Movies EN HD|Movies RU HD|Documentaries|TV|TV EN)\s
```

It's matching what described, but it also giving other info after Category line.

Wanna match only:

```
^Category:_whitespace_(Movies|Movies RU|Sports|Movies HD| Movies EN HD|Movies RU HD|Documentaries|TV|TV EN)_whitespace_
```

Everything that goes after last `_whitespace_` should be ignored.

What I'm forgetting?

Comment: can you give example_input/desired_output ?

Comment: Are you using `re.MULTILINE` or `re.DOTALL` in the call of `re.compile`?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/u5hy7ucF

Just a part of code, maybe it gives more info.

Comment: I think you need `r'^Category:\s*(Movies|Movies RU|Sports|Movies HD| Movies EN HD|Movies RU HD|Documentaries|TV|TV EN)\s'`, or even without `^` if you use it with `re.match`. Or, perhaps, `r'^Category:.*(Movies|Movies RU|Sports|Movies HD| Movies EN HD|Movies RU HD|Documentaries|TV|TV EN)\s'`. We need sample input and expected output (what exactly you want to match in that input).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew
Input: http://pastebin.com/itn9BCcP
Wanna remove those things and only leave Category.

Comment: You need BeautifulSoup because the input  is HTML.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew posted my solution on this.

Comment: Your solution goes against your requirements. I'd rather remove the post rather than posting the answer that no one else could come up with.

Answer (score 0):

`$` is symbol for end of line (simillary as `^` is symbol for beginning of the line) in regex.

Comment: This is not true for Python without any more details from your part.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i think sorted it out. It's not optimal solution, but it worked for me.

```
            p = re.compile(ur'^Category:.*?(Movies|Movies RU|Sports|Movies HD| Movies EN HD|Movies RU HD|Documentaries|TV|TV EN)\s')
            m = p.search(description)
            if m:
                final = m.group(0).replace('Category:', '')
            else:
                final = 'None'
```